# HTML File link - force download always

Tags: html, django, browser, download, server

I have a Django view that renders a list of uploaded files, and the user can click on them to begin the download.

When the project was deployed, we found there's one file that browsers open instead of download it. It seems related to the .dxf extension.

This is how the link is created:

```
<a href="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ file.url }}" target="blank">...</a>
```

As a result:

```
http://localhost:8003/media/folder/whatever.dxf
```

So, why the same browser behaves differently? if I run it on localhost, then it downloads the file. But accessing the real server, it'd open it. Can I prevent the server to open them in browsers?

Comment: It depends on the server configuration. The browser can chose to display the file in the browser, as it usually does with PDF and txt files. You either need to set headers to force download, or configure the webserver for this

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding new Django view that will handle download.

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^download/$', views.DownloadView.as_view(), name='download')
]
```

**views.py**

```
import urllib
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.generic.base import View


class DownloadView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        location = request.GET.get('location')
        file = urllib.urlretrieve(location)
        contents = open(file[0], 'r')
        content_type = '%s' % file[1].type
        response = HttpResponse(contents, content_type=content_type)
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="%s"' % location.split('/')[-1]
        return response
```

**template.html**

```
<a href="/download/?location={{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ file.url }}">...</a>
```